# Where to keep "global" view and actions in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app with AngularJS and it is going well, but I have a problem with understanding where and how to code global stuff like the process of logging out for instance?

I have a link in the right upper corner that will remove the user cookies when clicked. There is probably a common approach for sharing the code of actual doing so? Do you set up a controller hierachy where you inherit actions? Do some broadcasting magic? Directive?

I need some help with how to do this.

Comment: I think you could use angular service

Comment: Yeah, I have created a service. But the service must be called from a common controller or something since the logout link is on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define service - something  like this:

```
app.service('Auth', function() {
  var auth = {};

  auth.loggedIn = false;

  auth.login = function() {
    auth.loggedIn = true;
  };

  auth.logout = function() {
    auth.loggedIn = false;
  };

  return auth;
});
```

The above code sample is taken from article titled [Consuming services](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/consuming-services/) which I highly recommend. By reading it you will get insight of how services can be used.

**[Update]**

I believe you have two options on how to use this service. You can use it one of the Controllers of you aplication (like it is us used in provided article) or you could create a reusable Directive.

There is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLV9q/) demonstrating the first option where service is injected in top most controller and exposed trough top most scope. The child scopes prototypically inherits from parent scope so that's the reason that you can access the service also in child scopes.

Comment: Yeah, I have created this service. But I need to call this service from somewhere. Do I have a own controller for the logout link that I add with `ng-controller="LogoutController"` and then invoke the service or what?

Comment: Just inject the service into the `Controller` or `Directive` to use it. Please read trough the article I've provided.

Comment: Yeah, but the whole question is which contorller? I don't want to inject it into each controller since the logout button shall work everywhere. So this main controller becomes global?

Comment: Then you should inject it in the top most controller.

Comment: But is it okey to add one "main controller" on a container div like the link does, and then have another controller that is created through the route service? The question is, is it okey to have several  controllers pr view? Not only one that is created through the route service.

Comment: Yes, it is okay to do this (see provided JSFiddle).

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome article i came across yesterday outlining login stuff and angular:

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/7bbf0346acec

But the short answer yes, I agree, it should be in a service - ie singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Use services. You could create a $user or $auth service which will do the actual login/logout and loading of current user info, permission checks etc. controllers an other services should use this service for doing user/auth related stuff.

This applys for other things as well. Like if you must share data or provide common APIs for controllers/directives to use.